# how can i save the data to a text file after every loop?

Tags: c#

I have a for loop (slowed down by a timer) and every second the loop save the date on a text file. but if i close the program before the process ends, the text file remains.

the thing is when i present in class, i will not have enough time to waste waiting for the program to end, and at the same time i need to suspend the thread at sometime so i can't just use a smaller loop and risk not having enough time to suspend and resume.

is there a way to save the file after every loop? so whenever i exit (form based application) i would have some data there?

Comment: If you desire a better answer than "Yes there is a way" then I would suggest that you post the code that you are having trouble with and maybe explain better what the problem is.

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ?

Comment: is this winforms, wpf or ?

Comment: Why not show the code in question so that it won't lead to many assumptions?

Comment: nevermind, lazyberezovsky got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [StreamWriter.AutoFlush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush.aspx) property to `true`. That will make writer flush its buffer to the underlying file stream after every call to StreamWriter.Write.

```
using(var writer = File.AppendText("fileName"))
{
    writer.AutoFlush = true;
    foreach(string line in lines)
        writer.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have another loop (also with a timer with less time) that always saves the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this as saving to text file:

It will read old text and save old text and new text to it...

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path);
string old = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
sw.WriteLine(old);
sw.WriteLine(date);
sw.Close();
```

Or you can make StreamWriter as public and on Form Closing event you can save it on closing...
`public StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter("C:\\...")`